# Navigation Drawer with 2 or more different listviews from the same side

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

So I have already read from [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) and from [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

I am trying to have two or more different listviews.

Basically the scenario is the user to be able to click to 3 different buttons and have three different listviews. So I have two thoughts or I will create 3 listviews and with onClickListener I will open a different ListView or else a dynamic Listview that for every button to show a different listview but without changing the actual layout of the listview.

And I also have one sub question:

Is it possible to block the sliding navigation drawer from the sides? because I want him only to be able to open it from a button click. (I have already the code for button click, but I don't how to block the drawer from opening when I slide the side).

So any help??

Comment: it is generally considered bad ux (user experience) design to have multiple levels in the navigation drawer...

Comment: So instead what can I do? any ideas?

Comment: I did my navigation drawer with this tutorial: http://www.michenux.net/android-navigation-drawer-748.html

This helped me to create 3 different sections in the navigation drawer. I then used static variables to determine which button on which section was clicked. So I could have 3 option sections and combine them

Comment: But I don't want to do 3 different sections inside the listview. I want 3 different listview. It's totally different. Anyway thanks for the tutorial, I am sure it will help me with other things.

Any other ideas?